# Term for a phrase meant to end an argument.

Tags: terminology, argumentation

Is there a word for "a phrase which is intended to end discourse?"

such as

"That's just the way it is"

or

"If you don't like it, you can get out"

or

"Deal with it"

These statements are used in lieu of an argument or evidence.  They are meant to be the final word but do not contribute new information to the argument. People defend it by claiming no fallacy was made because no argument was made; However, these dialog stoppers are made as a retort during an argument.  what is this type of retort called?

Comment: In the theorem prover Coq, one ends a proof with "Qed." I don't suppose that is what you are referring to. That would depend on the software implementation. I assume what you are referring to is a dialog between two human beings arguing with each other and they now want to stop arguing. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: I do not think that there is a label for such expressions; at least, I have never heard of one. But inventing such a label would be a fun exercise for followers of this SE.

Comment: I think that this would be a thought-terminating argument, or cliché.
Here is the Wikipedia article about it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought-terminating_clich%C3%A9

Answer (score 2):

In a sense, these are almost [fatalistic](https://web.mit.edu/holton/www/pubs/determinism&fatalism.pdf) [resignations](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resignation) – they confer submission to ideas that are apparently immutable (to me, "deal with it," "that's just the way it is," and "if you don't like it, you can get out" all suggest this element of powerlessness).

If the speaker uses these statements in the context of ending discourse in a quasi-threatening way, then I would describe these as [ultimatums](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ultimatum) since they imply consequences ("you can get out") for not acquiescing to the speaker's perspective.

Comment: Acceptance or resignation isn't required. I usually say: "If *you* say so"  - not believing what you say or resigned to its consequence.